# Whenever I load up my .py it closes Instantly

Tags: python

I'm New to Python and I'm creating a multiple path game but whenever I open it up in the .py it closes instantly! So if anyone could help me out here it would be much apprecitated!

Heres my code:

```
def Roadto1stWin():
print("You have just joined the world of CounterStrike")
print("3 Hours later")
print("You have now got to rank 2 so you can finally play comp")
print("You find yourself playing a game of Comp on the map mirage")
print("Now that you have got to pistol round where do you go?")
print("Mid? B? or A?")
a = input("Type mid, b or a then hit 'Enter'.").lower()
if a ==("mid"):
   print("Okay nice you are going Mid")
   print("Where should you watch from?")
   print("Connector? Short? or Window?")
   b = input("Type connector, short or window Then hit 'Enter'.").lower()
   if b ==("connector"):
      print ("They rush B and kill the rest of your team and you lose the round")
      print ("Now your team are questioning your mid ability!")
      print ("Do you fight back and try to win the argument? or do you just carry on playing")
      c = input ("Type fight or play then hit 'Enter'.").lower()
      if c ==("fight"):
         print ("Your TeamMates end up not liking you and kick you")
      elif c ==("play"):
         print ("Another one of your teammates goes mid instead of you!")
         print ("You have decided to go B since there is only 1 at b")
         print ("Now your Teammate dies instantly at mid")
         print ("The enemy team win this round as well")
         print ("Now do you complain or play")
         d = input ("Type complain or play then hit 'Enter'.").lower()
         if d == ("play"):
            print ("Your team are mad at you for no voting to kick him so you get kicked")
            print ("The End")
         elif d == ("complain"):
              print ("Nice your team stand up with you and you kick the player")
              print ("Now that the player is gone your team have good chemistry")
              print ("You end up winning the game well done!")
        if b == ("short"):
           print ("You die instantly and since your team are full of Russians you get kicked")
           print ("The End")
        if b == ("window"):
           print ("You kill 3 of the enemies rushing mid and your teammates praise you!")
           print ("Now a second teammate has pushed short killing the player you were gonna kill!")
           print ("What do you do?")
           print ("argue at him or leave it alone")
           e = input ("Type argue or leave it then hit 'Enter'.").lower()
           if e == ("argue"):
              print ("Your team are toxic and don't like your attitude so they kick you")
              print ("The end")
           elif e == ("leave it"):
              print ("You get on well with each other and win the game")
```

Roadto1stWin()

This is the code!
Thank you for your replies

Comment: Treguna Mekoides Trecorum Satis Dee?

Comment: Maybe you have a syntax error. I'd run your code on my machine, but I can't copy-paste an image into Notepad. (hint, hint)

Comment: You double click on the script. The OS executes it, showing you the terminal (or CMD.exe), and then the script exits. What should the OS do? Right, close the terminal window.

Comment: Doesn't it take a lot more effort to take a screenshot, crop it, and upload it than it does to just copy and paste the text? It's certainly harder to read and try code in a screenshot, anyway - please replace the screenshot with text.

Comment: I have updated the post it is no the code not a picture Sorry!

Comment: Your indentation is off for the later `if b` lines, they're one space too far indented compared to the original `if b` lines, I think.

Comment: I see a lot of mixed tabs and spaces here. Those are going to cause you a lot of weird bugs, possibly including this one. Stick to one type of indentation; spaces are recommended.